# Can you say "to pursue a program"?

Tags: synonyms

Can you say "to pursue a program," as in "I am currently pursuing a program in Chinese language"? What are other suitable verbs to use in this case/are there any synonyms for "to take classes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say yes on the basis that a program (or programme) can be defined as "a set of related measures or activities with a particular long-term aim" so "I'm pursuing a set of related measures or activities with a particular long-term aim to learn Chinese" is a valid meaningful statement.

I'm deliberately avoiding getting into the debate about program vs programme because I don't want to provoke a traditionalist vs progressive holy war. Peace!